# Как сделать, чтобы текст при использовании textPath был всегда сверху?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Изучаю команду SVG: [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath), которая позволяет разместить текст вдоль криволинейной траектории.

Вот пример из теоретического источника: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <!-- to hide the path, it is usually wrapped in a <defs> element -->
  <!-- <defs> -->
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50" />
  <!-- </defs> -->

  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath">
      Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

Приведено много используемых атрибутов, но не хватает основного, как в [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)
`rotate ="auto"`

Как добиться нормального положения текста (не вниз головой ) на всех участках траектории?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим на примере, когда траектория представляет собой окружность.

Начало текста всегда совпадает с началом `path`, то есть с первой `M` в `<path d="M50 200"`

Чтобы нижнюю часть траектории заполнить буквами в нормальном расположении, нужно сделать её отдельно от верхней части.

*Верхняя половина окружности:*

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
 <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 0 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
 </svg>
```

**Добавляем нижнюю половину окружности:**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
     <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="2" />  
</svg>
```

**Обратите внимание**, что формулы для обоих половинок окружностей практически одинаковы, за исключением флага ***sweep-flag***, который отвечает за направление рисования по часовой -**1**
или против часовой - **0** ),   подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900#comm_a)

Теперь на верхнюю и нижнюю дугу с помощью `textPath` размещаем текст.

Ещё один нюанс, раз половинки текста стали самостоятельными, то для них можно выбрать разные атрибуты шрифтов. Например: `font-size="36px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey"`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:0px solid;" >  
         

   <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="2" />  
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="198" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" /> 

<text  dy="-12px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" fill="black" letter-spacing="6"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="5%"> Top arc outside text
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
  <text  dy="32px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="5"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#bottom"   startOffset="3%"> Bottom arc text outside
    </textPath> 
 </text>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Примеры анимации текста

В этих примерах анимации основаны на изменении `startOffset`, отступ текста от начала направляющей траектории (`path`)

```
<textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="98%"> Top arc outside text  
      <animate id="an" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="98%;3%" fill="freeze" />
    </textPath>
```

*#1. Одновременная анимация обоих половинок текста*

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:0px solid;" >  
         

   <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />  
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="198" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" /> 

<text  dy="-12px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" fill="black" letter-spacing="6"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="98%"> Top arc outside text  
      <animate id="an" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="98%;3%" fill="freeze" />
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
  <text  dy="32px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="5"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#bottom"   startOffset="98%"> Bottom arc text outside 
     <animate attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="98%;3%" fill="freeze" />
    </textPath> 
 </text>   
 <text  y="200" x="100" font-size="42px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="5"  >Click me </text>
 </svg>
```

#2. Поочередная анимация  половинок текста

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:0px solid;" >  
         

   <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />  
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="198" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" /> 

<text  dy="-12px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" fill="black" letter-spacing="6"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="98%"> Top arc outside text  
      <animate id="an" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;an2.end+1s" dur="2s" values="98%;3%" fill="freeze" />
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
  <text  dy="32px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="5"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#bottom"   startOffset="98%"> Bottom arc text outside 
     <animate id="an2" attributeName="startOffset" begin="an.end" dur="2s" values="98%;3%" fill="freeze" />
    </textPath> 
 </text>  
      <text  y="200" x="100" font-size="42px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="5"  >Click me </text>
 </svg>
```